# How to calculate Definite Integral in X to expression in X?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let **X** be a **continuous random variable** with probability density function (**PDF**)

$$ f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
cx^2+|x|, & -1/2 < x < 1/2 \\
0, & otherwise
\end{cases} $$

1. Determine the value of the c constant.
2. Obtain the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of X.

**Solution**

1. Having to be
   $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1, $$
   it is
   $$1=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} cx^2+|x| \, \mathrm{d}x=c\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}x^2\, \mathrm{d}x+\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}|x| \, \mathrm{d}x$$

By integrating it, we get:

$$1=c\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{-1/2}^{1/2}+\left[\frac{x|x|}{2}\right]_{-1/2}^{1/2}=c\left[\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^3-(-\frac{1}{2})^3}{3}\right]+\left[\frac{\frac{1}{2}|\frac{1}{2}|-(-\frac{1}{2}|-\frac{1}{2}|)}{2}\right]=$$
$$=c\frac{\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}}{3}+\frac{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}}{2}=c\frac{2}{8}\times\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{4}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{c}{12}+\frac{1}{4}$$

So we can conclude that:

$$c=12\times\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)=12\times\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)=3\times3=9$$
that matches with the solution provided by the book.

2. Now, for this step the book provides the following solution:
   [image]
   Probably here the integral of |x| has been splitted into 2 integrals (positive and negative numbers), however I'm not getting how it is possible to turn a definite integral with x variables to an expression of x variables, by passing from another integral by substituting **y=x**.

By integrating
$$9\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}x^2\, \mathrm{d}x+\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}|x| \, \mathrm{d}x$$

I would get only a number.

How do I turn this integral to an expression in x variables?

Comment: Integration is independent of change of variable.

Comment: I agree, just not getting how it concludes that the integral is equal to that expression

Comment: $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(r) \mathrm{d}r $.

Comment: Sorry, could you please make an example? What property/theorem should I use?

Comment: What is the definition of CDF? You don't seem to be using that.

Comment: It is the the function provided at point 2 of solution. In my language it is simply distribution function, but according to wikipedia should be the same https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: @1Z10 I am asking you did you check the definition of distribution function? Because it is not matching with what you have done for the CDF.

Comment: Well, yes. However I did only calculate the value o the c constant. Which is correct according to the solution provided by the book. I didn't start yet the point 2, since I do not know how to pass from a definite integral to an expression in X, instead of a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF $F_X(x)$ of a random variable $X$ is the probability that $X$ takes values smaller than $x$, so 
$$
F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(x')\mathrm{d}x'\ .
$$
Everything boils down to computing the following integral:
$$
F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \mathrm{d}x'(9x'^2+|x'|)\mathbb{1}_{-1/2\leq x'\leq 1/2}.
$$
Clearly, this is a function of $x$, not just a number!

To compute the integral, we first observe that, if $x<-1/2$ the integral is zero (because the integrand is zero), and if $x>1/2$ the integral is identical to $\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \mathrm{d}x'(9x'^2+|x'|)$ and thus is $=1$ by normalization.

Since the integrand is zero if $x'<-1/2$, we can truncate the range of integration as follows:
$$
F_X(x)=\int_{-1/2}^x \mathrm{d}x'(9x'^2+|x'|)\mathbb{1}_{x'\leq 1/2}.
$$

Now, it is convenient to consider the cases $-1/2<x<0$ and $0<x<1/2$ separately. If $-1/2<x<0$, you are integrating the function $9x'^2+|x'|$ over a negative range, which means that $|x'|= -x'$, and your integral is
$$
F_X(x)=\int_{-1/2}^x \mathrm{d}x'(9x'^2-x')=9x'^3/3-x'^2/2\Big|_{-1/2}^x
=9x^3/3-x^2/2-\frac{9}{3}(-1/2)^3+\frac{1}{2}(-1/2)^2=
$$
$$
3 x^3-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ ,
$$
which coincides with the result given.

If $0<x<1/2$ instead, one needs to be more careful, because the function is now integrated over both a negative and positive range, therefore it is convenient to split the integration range $(-1/2,x)$ into $(-1/2,0)$ and $(0,x)$ - the difference between the two resulting integrals being that the absolute value $|x'|$ is equal to $-x'$ in the first case, and $x'$ in the second case.

Comment: How do you turn
$$
\int_{-\infty}^x \mathrm{d}x'(9x'^2+|x'|)\mathbb{1}_{-1/2\leq x\leq 1/2}.
$$
to
$$
1+6x^3+|x|^2
$$
?

Comment: @1Z10 What is your background? How familiar are you with definite integrals?

Comment: I did study about it at high school and University few years ago, but never had to deal with such transformation.

Comment: @1Z10 Edited the answer, let me know if it's clearer now.

Comment: thanks for your time and patience,  I needed to recall a bit  of stuff, but now it's more clear.
Just a question about the case $$0<x<\frac{1}{2}$$
Since x is always positive, why "function is now integrated over both a negative and positive range"? Where the negative sign comes from, given that in this case |x| = x being x > 0?

Comment: @1Z10 Because you are still integrating between $-1/2$ and $x$...so $x'$ (the integration variable) can still take both negative and positive values. Do not confuse $x$ and $x'$, they are two very different objects: $x$ plays the role of a parameter, which can take values between (in principle) $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, while $x'$ is the integration variable - which, depending on the value of $x$, can take values in a certain range of values....

Comment: Ok. My fault, I was confusing the range of x with the bounds of the integral, so not taking into account values of x' lower than 0.